# ForEach Error: Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach, binding

I have two custom types: `Weekday` and `Shift` as shown below,

```
struct Weekday: Identifiable {

    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var index: Int
    var shifts: [Shift]
}

struct Shift: Identifiable, Encodable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date
}
```

I also have a variable in a class `AvailabilityManager`:

```
@Published var selectedWeekdays = [Weekday]
```

In my main view, I am trying to display a subview for each selected `weekday`. Additionally, within that subview, I want to display another subview for each `shift`.

```
ForEach(availabilityManager.selectedWeekdays.sorted(by: {$0.index < $1.index})) { weekday in

    VStack {
    
        Text(weekday.name)
    
        ForEach(weekday.shifts) { shift in
            HStack {
                DatePicker("Start: ", selection: shift.startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                DatePicker("End: ", selection: shift.endTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

However, with the above code, I get the following errors:
`Cannot convert value of type '[Shift]' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'` and `Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred`.

I then changed the overarching `forEach` to `ForEach($availabilityManager.selectedWeekdays...`

However, that gives the error `Referencing operator function '<' on 'Comparable' requires that 'Binding<Int>' conform to 'Comparable'`

Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT:
These values are preset in the `AvailablityManager` class. The method provided does not allow me to change the values of `startTime` and `endTime`

```
    @Published var weekdays: [Weekday] = [
        Weekday(name: "Sunday", index: 0, shifts: [Shift(startTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date(), endTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date())]),
        Weekday(name: "Monday", index: 1, shifts: [Shift(startTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date(), endTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date())]),
        Weekday(name: "Tuesday", index: 2, shifts: [Shift(startTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date(), endTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date())]),
        Weekday(name: "Wednesday", index: 3, shifts: [Shift(startTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date(), endTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date())]),
        Weekday(name: "Thursday", index: 4, shifts: [Shift(startTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date(), endTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date())]),
        Weekday(name: "Friday", index: 5, shifts: [Shift(startTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date(), endTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date())]),
        Weekday(name: "Saturday", index: 6, shifts: [Shift(startTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date(), endTime: Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) ?? Date())])
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with value in case of ForEach with `Binding` use `wrappedValue` accessor, like

```
ForEach($availabilityManager.selectedWeekdays.sorted(by: {$0.wrappedValue.index < $1.wrappedValue.index})) { weekday in
    VStack {
        Text(weekday.wrappedValue.name)
        ForEach(weekday.shifts) { shift in
            HStack {
                DatePicker("Start: ", selection: shift.startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                DatePicker("End: ", selection: shift.endTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: @devOP1 this is the correct answer, the reason the `$availabilityManager` is used because we would get bindings, that way we can pass the bindings as the `DatePicker` expects bindings

Comment: I must say, however, it does not allow me to change the value of the `shift.startTime` and `shift.endTime`

Comment: I assume it is due to sorting (which makes copies), make sorting not on the fly but inside view model.

Comment: @Asperi I have edited the question a bit to include the preset data. How would I be able to sort the data in the viewModel?

Comment: It's different question, out of the topic.

Comment: @Asperi I have added the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73224870/values-of-datepicker-not-changing. If you care to answer it :)